# What is another word for a weak or unsatisfying (to the viewer) smile?

Tags: synonyms, poetry

I'm writing a poem about someone who smiles in a very vague way that leaves something to be desired. I've thought about words like unreadable, empty and vague, but not really "enigmatic". Their smile is mysterious and hard to read, but not in a way that they are hiding something or there is something that they aren't saying. It's more that their smile is disappointing to the viewer, as if they wanted more from that smile. Any ideas?

Here is some context:

> ...I grabbed her hand and she smiled her ***unreadable*** smile but didn't squeeze or withdraw...

Comment: It could be an inscutible smile

Comment: Do you mean inscrutable? I like that!

Comment: Sort of Mona Lisa's smile?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like writing advice

Comment: Oops, yes with an 'r'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My **insipid** smile is a very **watery** smile. You might say it's a **washed out** smile.

Websters/ARTFL [Insipid](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=insipid&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search):

> Wanting in spirit, life, or animation; uninteresting; weak; vapid; flat; dull; heavy;

Collins: [Watery](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/watery):

> 4. insipid, thin, or weak

Merriam Webster [Washed out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/washed-out):

> 2:   depleted in vigor or animation

Comment: Watery! Its perfect because the word isn't too complicated, and I like the idea of a "diluted" smile. Thanks, mate!